# Python 3 TKinter Window will not open until command has been executed

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I was working on a program testing the .pack_forget() command in TKinter, but encountered a problem. I had a time.sleep() command in my code, and the TKinter window will not open until the time.sleep() command has been executed in IDLE. Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
import time
main = Tk()
main.title("Test")
myLabel = Label(main, text="I'm a Label", fg="black")
myLabel.pack()
time.sleep(3)
myLabel.pack_forget()
```

If you know why this issue is occurring, please answer.

Comment: where is your "main.mainloop()"?

Comment: `time.sleep()` does exactly what it says. It puts the entire program to sleep. While it is sleeping it can't respond to events, such as for requests to redraw the screen.

Answer (score 1):

`time.sleep()` puts the entire program to sleep, so that it cannot do anything.

You should instead use:

```
main.after(3000, myLabel.pack_forget)
```

to run `myLabel.pack_forget()` after 3000 miliseconds, i.e. 3 seconds.

Comment: The program still waits the 3 seconds before opening the window. Do you know any other possible ways to do this?